# Can't connect to Node inside Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

Hello i created a docker image for a node app :

Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step
 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]

RUN npm install 

RUN npm i -g @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-loader

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

i buil it then i run using this command :

```
docker run  --publish 5000:5000   nodeApp
```

it runs normally without errors but when i try to connect to it i can't

my request is  : http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth/login  but i don't have response

result of docker ps

[image]

Comment: what does docker ps show? Also try it once with localhost too.

Comment: docker ps return my runned container , i try using localhost and 0.0.0.0 but still not working

Comment: could u post a screenshot of docker ps?

Comment: yes , i add it in description

Comment: `docker ps` usually prints out text, and its text contents would be much more readable than that screen shot.  Can you also include the code (again, as text) that sets up the network listener?  (Is it explicitly set to listen only on 127.0.0.1?)

Comment: i have only one runned container , that's the result of docker ps , wich code do you mean?